# Python: How to extract from a DF a column that will be the index and that vluese is boolean 0 or 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

we are using this df:

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
heart_df=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Turgibot/BigData/master/DataSets/heart_d.csv")
```

---

We need to Plot the TenYearRisk of disease over the age distribution.
output should be like this:

```
      Yes          No
age     
32  0.000000    1.000000
33  0.000000    1.000000
34  0.000000    1.000000
35  0.060606    0.939394
36  0.025974    0.974026
```

I think we need to use pivot_table but dont know how to split the columns to yes and no.
I got only this:

---

```
   pivot = heart_df.pivot_table(index=heart_df.age, values='TenYearCHD')
```

---

and the output is:

```
    TenYearCHD
age
32  0.000000
33  0.000000
34  0.000000
35  0.060606
36  0.025974
```

Comment: You need an average of yes and no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on the dataframe.

```
heart_df.groupby('age').mean().TenYearCHD
```

yields

```
age                                                                                                                     
32    0.000000                                                                                                          
33    0.000000                                                                                                                      
34    0.000000                                                                                                          
35    0.047619
....
```

edit:

To get exactly the result you want, do this:

```
hd = heart_df.groupby('age').mean().TenYearCHD
nHd = 1. - hd
pd.DataFrame({'Yes':hd,'No':nHd})
```

yields

```
      Yes        No
age
32   0.000000  1.000000
33   0.000000  1.000000
34   0.000000  1.000000
35   0.047619  0.952381
36   0.035714  0.964286
```

Comment: there  is any way that  i can do it without 1-result?